# Is it possible to animate an object's location in html with Angular 2?

Tags: animation, angular

I've been experimenting with animation in Angular 2, and it's really useful for some things. However, I have a navagation menu, and I'd love to animate an object to slide up and down the list to highlight the users selection, something like material design's tabs, but vertical.

Here's my list:

```
<md-nav-list>
    <md-list-item class="inverted nav-list-item" [routerLink]="['/home']">
        <p class="mdl-navigation__link">Home</p>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="inverted" [routerLink]="['/counter']">
        <p class="mdl-navigation__link">Counter</p>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="inverted" [routerLink]="['/fetch-data']">
        <p class="mdl-navigation__link" >Fetch data</p>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="inverted" [routerLink]="['/ship-info']">
        <div style="width: 6px; height: 100%; background-color: orange; margin-right: 20px;"></div>
        <p class="mdl-navigation__link" >Ship Info</p>
    </md-list-item>
    <md-list-item class="inverted" [routerLink]="['/data-analysis']">
        <p class="mdl-navigation__link" >Data Analysis</p>
    </md-list-item>
</md-nav-list>
```

[image]

Is it possible to animate the transition of the orange `<div>` to slide to a different list item with angular animations? Or am I stuck having the div outside the list, and trying to get the correct pixel position for an animation using TranslateY? The only information I can find in the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) is on changing an object's properties (like background image), or it's absolute x,y location on the screen (say sliding in/out).

Comment: Do you have any "selected" class on the links? Can you tell which one is active?

Comment: I don't currently have any way of tracking the selected item, though I could create a directive that did so?

Comment: Well, you have a much simpler approach. Just add a `border-left: 3px solid orange; padding-left: 20px; ` to the currently active element

Comment: But there would be no animation in that case. It would just appear, rather than "slide" to the correct item.

Comment: Got you, you want it to slide between items, vertically. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes! I've edited the wording of the post a little to make that clearer.